# CSV file data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a .csv file containing list of companies. I want to upload that .csv file so it will update the database, and in WordPress I want to see that data and edit it too.

I tried Custom Post type (ecpt plugin) and created the post type and created the meta-boxes each for one field, but I cannot show those values in the post fields. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After you create a custom post type, you need to enter your data.

And you need to make sure your template is coded to display that data.

As far as uploading a CSV, unless ECPT has that capability, you'll to use something like phpmyadmin to import the CSV into the database.

Comment: how to make template to be coded that it show that , i want to show the data to the PAGE . and i want to show only metabox data is it possible ?

Comment: @user1224233 I don't use a plugin for custom post types, I code them myself. It's not hard. Here is a simple tutorial that should get you through it: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-wordpress-custom-post-type